# Capturing image storing in UIimage view showing landscape direction

Tags: iphone, ipod

I wrote the code for camara application. The view having one button and one `UIimageview`. When I click on camera, camera will open after capturing image and when I click on use button it is showing some part only in the `UIimageview` that too in landscape direction.

Answer (score -1):

```
CGSize size=CGSizeMake(editView.bounds.size.width,editView.bounds.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[editView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImageCaptureSend = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImageCapture, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: when i capturing image in portrait camara UIimage is giving horizantal image.when i taking landscape mode it is giving vertically...

Comment: You should really give an explanation of what your code does and what the OP forgot to consider when writing his application. Just posting a bit of code is neither helpful for the OP nor for anyone else having the same problem. Maybe, just maybe, the OP's problem will be solved, but I doubt they will learn something new.